# Laravel - Model class, overriding main methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a BLOB field in my database which contains compressed data.

I need compress / uncompress to be transparent, and user class do not need to write:

```
$objModel->field = gzencode($objModel->field);
$objModel->field = gzdecode($objModel->field);
```

For saving I got it, overriding save method:

```
public function save($attributes[] = null) {
    $this->field = gzencode($objModel->field);
    return parent::save($attributes);    
}
```

But when I recover data from the database I do not get to gzdecode "transparent", I have tried overriding boot, __call, __callstatic and others, but unsuccessfully.

Can someone tell me which method recovers data from DB and fills the model object so I can override it and make gzdecode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you override Eloquent methods. Just use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getFieldAttribute($value)
{
    return gzdecode($value);
}
```

And [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator):

```
public function setFieldAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['field'] = gzencode($value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @alexey-mezenin ! I saw these but i read too much fast and did not notice "will be automatically called". Your answer has really helped me. Greetings!